# Why is $f_t= \gamma^{'}_s$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

I am currently working on the first variation formula of energy and I use this file [here](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ewangzuoq/Courses/16S-RiemGeom/Notes/Lec12.pdf) to understand this notion.. We are working on the following construction:

Let $\gamma : [a,b] \to M$ be a smooth curve, and $\epsilon >0$. A variation of $\gamma$ is a smoot map $f :[a,b] \times (-\epsilon, \epsilon)\to M$ so that
$$f(t,0)=\gamma(t)$$
for all $t \in [a,b]$. In what follows, we will also denote $\gamma_s(t)=f(t,s)$.

Let $f$ be a varation of $\gamma$. For simplicity we will denote
$$f_s:= df(\frac{\partial}{\partial s}), \;\;\;\;f_t:=df(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}) $$

By definition we have $f_t= \gamma^{'}_s$.

Why do we have this: $f_t= \gamma^{'}_s$? I mean we have that $\gamma'_s(t)= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \gamma_s(t)= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(t,s)$. Why is this now equal to $df(\frac{\partial}{\partial t})$? What do I oversee? Many thanks for some help!

Comment: Write down the definition of $df_p(\partial/\partial t)$.

Comment: My problem is to understand what actually $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ means..

Comment: You're reading about first variation of energy and you don't know the standard notation of basic differentiable manifolds? $\partial/\partial s,\partial/\partial t$ is in this case the standard basis for $(s,t)$-space. In general, if you have local coordinates $x=(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ on a manifold, $\partial/\partial x^i$ is the vector field tangent to the $x^i$-curves on the manifold; it has the property that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} = D_i(f\circ x^{-1}),$$ where $D_i$ denotes the $i$th partial derivative in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Thanks for more details! Do you maybe have a link or a book where I can read more about it? How does this helps me now with my problem?

Comment: It answers your question immediately. How does $f$ change as you move in the $t$ direction? Look at any standard differentiable manifolds book. Lee, Boothby, Spivak volume 1 (of 5).

Answer (score 1):

By definition, at each $(t_0, s_0) \in [a, b] \times (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$,  $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right\vert_{(t_0, s_0)} \cong (1, 0)$ and $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\right\vert_{(t_0, s_0)} \cong (0, 1)$ are tangent vectors living in $T_{(t_0, s_0)}([a,b] \times (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)) \cong T_{(t_0, s_0)} \mathbb{R}^2$ which act on real smooth functions (actually germs of functions, but that's not important now) $h: U_{(t_0, s_0)} \to \mathbb{R} $ defined on a neighbourhood of $(t_0, s_0)$ by

$$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right\vert_{(t_0, s_0)} (h) \doteq \left.\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}\right\vert_{(t_0, s_0)} = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{h(t_0+ \delta, s_0) - h(t_0, s_0)}{\delta} = \mathrm{d}h_{(t_0, s_0)}((1, 0))$$

and
$$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\right\vert_{(t_0, s_0)} (h) \doteq \left.\frac{\partial h}{\partial s}\right\vert_{(t_0, s_0)} = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{h(t_0, s_0 + \delta) - h(t_0, s_0)}{\delta} = \mathrm{d}h_{(t_0, s_0)}((0, 1))$$

Similarly, at each $(t_0, s_0) \in [a, b] \times (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$, $\left. \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right\vert_{(t_0, s_0)}$ is defined by:
$$\left. \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right\vert_{(t_0, s_0)} = \mathrm{d}f_{(t_0, s_0)}\left(\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right\vert_{(t_0, s_0)}  \right) = \mathrm{d}f_{(t_0, s_0)}((1, 0))$$

Let us fix $s_0 \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ and consider the curve $\gamma_{s_0}: [a, b] \to M$ given by $\gamma_{s_0}(t) = f(t, s_0)$. If we define the curve $\alpha_{s_0} : [a, b] \to [a, b] \times (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ by $\alpha_{s_0}(t) = (t, s_0)$, then we have by the chain rule:

\begin{aligned}
\gamma_{s_0}'(t) = (f \circ \alpha_{s_0})'(t) &= \mathrm{d}f_{\alpha_{s_0}(t)}(\alpha_{s_0}'(t)) \\
&=  \mathrm{d}f_{(t, s_0)}((1, 0)) \\
&= \left. \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right\vert_{(t, s_0)}
\end{aligned}
as desired.